# Text row with buttons aligned on right

Tags: html, css

I have a simple element which contains a text with a variable length and on the right of the row there are two buttons.

This is the markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <h1>Quem in fabulas et dolore, fore hic est elit 
laborum, nam malis consectetur sed si nisi despicationes.</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="btn btn-default">My button</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Another btn</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FBuZb/

It should looks like this image:

[image]

The problem is that, if the text is too long or the window is too thin I get this:

[image]

You can see the buttons overflow the text.

I already use this CSS to prevent text from go to next line:

```
.row h1 {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But this doesn't solve the problem with the buttons.
I can't know the width of the `.buttons` element because the labels can be translated in different languages with different length.

I think I should use flex-box but I'm not practice with it.
How can I solve this problem without use of javascript?

**NB: I don't want to set a fixed width to my row**

Comment: fiddle please, your code can't show the result as in your image.

Comment: You can try using CSS table layout http://jsfiddle.net/FBuZb/4/ , it requires you to set the fixed width for the buttons group, you can also use relative width but it depends on the buttons group, if they are fixed in number and text, using fixed width for the buttons group is better.

Comment: I don't know the width of my buttons...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
button
{
float:right;
}


<p>
  <button class="btn btn-default">My button</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Another btn</button>
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
</p>
```

try this example

```
<div class="row">
         <button class="btn btn-default">My button</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Another btn</button>
       <h1>Quem in fabulas et dolore, fore hic est elit 
        laborum, nam malis consectetur sed si nisi despicationes.</h1>    
</div>

h1 {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 400;
            padding: 6px;
            margin: 0;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

button
{
float:right;
}
```

Comment: No I don't want to set a fixed width.

Comment: ok actually it works, was enough invert the position of text and buttons seems... Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/FBuZb/19/

Comment: @FezVrasta. Glad can help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [word-wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)

```
.row h1  {
   word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

change this,

```
.buttons {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px;
    float:right;
}
```

add div to h1 ans set css,

```
.text{
    width:70%;
}
```

see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2jgh2/2/)

Comment: Not a solution, I already fix this problem with the CSS I've provided, I've another problem in this question.

Comment: I want to prevent buttons from cover text.

Comment: then button display at last, when text is end?

Comment: I just want text and buttons not overlapped. I don't know how to explain it in a better way.

Comment: ok i change code ,see this it will according to your question??